# peverify ClassLayout has parent TypeDef marked AutoLayout

Tags: .net, cil, mono.cecil

After converting my compiler to use Mono.Cecil instead of Reflection.Emit, I am getting an error from peverify.

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework PE Verifier.  Version  4.0.30319.33440
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

[MD]: Error: ClassLayout has parent TypeDef token=0x02000002 marked AutoLayout. [token:0x00000001]
1 Error(s) Verifying test.exe
```

I have not been able to find any information on what this means. I can provide the executable if needed.

Comment: Have you looked at a diff of disassembly of your code using both methods? What is the difference? Also, could you provide a minimal sample code that generates assembly that causes the above error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only describe what the validation error means, I cannot theorize what caused it from the provided information.  This is a bug in the metadata of the assembly you generated.  In particular, the ClassLayout table, section II.22.8 in Ecma-335.  Underlying error code is VLDTR_E_CL_TDAUTO, 0x80131229, "ClassLayout parent TypeDef is marked AutoLayout".

The ClassLayout table contains records for types that were declared with explicit layout.  in C#, types with the [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] or [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] attribute applied.  LayoutKind.Auto is the default for classes without the attribute.  The validator double-checks the records in the ClassLayout table and matches them with the corresponding record in the TypeDef table.  You violated rule #3:

> The Class or ValueType indexed by Parent shall be SequentialLayout or
>   ExplicitLayout (§II.23.1.15). (That is, AutoLayout types shall not own any rows in
>   the ClassLayout table.) [ERROR]

Comment: It looks like the issue was that an empty struct cannot have an auto layout. Is there any chance you could add some information on how to view the tables you had listed?